# JPA Criteria API IN expression Parameter list

Tags: java, jpa, expression, criteria-api

Is there a possibility to use a parameter list in Criteria API .in expression?

I have something like this:

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    list.add((long)1);
    list.add((long)2);
    list.add((long)3);


CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Bewerbung> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Bewerbung.class);
Root<Bewerbung> bewerbung = criteriaQuery.from(Bewerbung.class);

criteriaQuery.select(bewerbung).where(
cb.in(bewerbung.get(Bewerbung_.bewerberNummer)).value(list);

return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

The expression `.value(list)` does not work as `value()` is expecting a paramter of type long not a list. 
In my case it is not possible to use a subquery.
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 37):

No need to use `CriteriaBuilder#isTrue`. This should suffice:

```
criteriaQuery.select(bewerbung)
             .where(bewerbung.get(Bewerbung_.bewerberNummer)
             .in(list));
```

Comment: Instead of "no need" I would say "must not". At least using EclipseLink 2.6.2 for sure. I have tested.

Comment: @MiklosKrivan well, both should work, this just looks clearer to me.

Comment: I would expect so as well but unfortunately using EclipseLink 2.6.2 for ORM (I have tried both formula) the isTrue() wrapping raises the mentioned exception. That is why my wording suggestion given. So theoretically "no need" but practically "must not".

Comment: @MiklosKrivan will have to check, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MiklosKrivan can you, please, share your stack trace on `pastebin` or someplace else, if possible?

Answer (score 34):

```
cb.isTrue(bewerbung.get(Bewerbung_.bewerberNummer).in(list));
```

should do the trick, AFAIK.

Comment: Great, thanks this works, but I'm using Hibernate and it seems that  Hibernate doesn't support empty collection as parameter of javax.persistence.criteria.Expression "in" method parameter. See http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-issues/2011-December/035927.html

Comment: AFAIK, no-one supports them. You should probably short-circuit the query in case an empty list is passed as argument.

Comment: I have found this expression (wrapped in isTrue) raises exception PREDICATE_PASSED_TO_EVALUATION in EclipseLink 2.6.2 but without isTrue wrapping works perfect as predicate in my example probably because "in" returns with Predicate object.