# JPA criteria instead of uncommon HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, criteria

I want to write a jpa Predicate to get criteria query giving the same result as this HQL query:

```
from Profile P WHERE (:interests) in P.profileInterests
```

, where "interests" is a method parameter ( List of Strings )
and profileInterests is a field of Profile entity class (also List of Strings).

I still get ClassCastException.

Comment: Use `root.get(profileInterests).in(interests)`.

Comment: You mean  `predicates.add(root.get("profileInterests").in(interests))`  ? I get `java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.base/java.util.List`when I apply that, and if I don't apply, just leave it blank, and create query with other predicates, like `predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("city"), city )) `, it executes properly.

Comment: No, you cannot use `IN` for collection IN collection, as per what the JPA spec says. Multiple clauses are needed for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Criteria API IN expression Parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732970/jpa-criteria-api-in-expression-parameter-list)